# if a check box is check with my query

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

```
FindInsurance(
 @Amount DECIMAL(18,2),
 @Freight DECIMAL(18,2),
 @FreightType VARCHAR(50),
 @UseFreight BIT
) AS
SET @FreightType = (Select FreightType From tblFreight Where FreightType= @FreightType)
SET @UseFreight = (Select UseFreight From tblFreight Where UseFreight= 'TRUE')

IF FreightType = @FreightType and UseFreight= @UseFreight
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
     SELECT
        FreightType,InsuranceRate,InsuranceRate * (@Amount + @Freight) AS Insurance
       FROM
        tblFreight
Else 
SELECT
        FreightType,InsuranceRate,InsuranceRate * (@Amount) AS Insurance
       FROM
        tblFreight
END
End If
```

i would like to be able to select a fright name and if the check box is check them it calculate if false it do a different calculation

Comment: Please learn how to use the `{}` button in the editor to format code.

Comment: sure i would love to but i am completely new to this

Comment: You can edit this or previous questions of yours and see how it's done.

Comment: ok what about help with my problem?

Comment: no worry i figure it out on my own thanks youtube